# member.ban is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this inside my main `index.js` to check for any blacklisted users to prevent them from joining if they tried to join back again.

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  if(member.user.bot)
  if (!db.get("blacklist_users").find({ user_id: member.id }).value()) {
      return;
  } else {
    member.ban();
      member.send("**You are blacklisted.**")
  }
})

bot.on('message', message => {
  let member = message.author;
  if(!db.get("blacklist_users").find({ user_id: member.id }).value()) {
      return;
  }else {
      member.ban();
      member.send("**You are blacklisted.**")
  }
})
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but doesn't your `if(member.user.bot)` prevent any of that first event listener from running on regular users?

Comment: that is only to prevent actual bots to join and not user accounts.

Comment: If you solved the issue and you believe it will help others, please post an answer to your question rather than editing the question itself. If you don't believe it will be useful to other people, you can delete the question. (I've rolled back the edit that replaced the question with your solution)

Comment: thank you DBS i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Always be sure to check the API documentation for types.  In this case, [message.author](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, not a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object.  User does not have a ban function because it isn't associated with a guild.  If you need the member object you will need to retrieve it from the member property.

```
let member = message.member;
```

Just be wary that this may be undefined if the message did not originate in a guild (i.e. Direct Message) or the member has left the guild before it is executed.

Comment: thank you but i have it fixed now, had to add some changes and move the first event to where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

So i got it solved now by moving the code to my event instead of leaving it in the main file. And of course i had to define some other stuff in order to read where the blacklisted user is.

```
if (!db.get("blacklist_users").find({ user_id: member.id }).value()) {
  return;
} else {
  member.ban()
  console.log(`User "${member.user.username}" has joined tried to join "${member.guild.name} and is probably blacklisted` )
}
```

i hope this will help you guys